# How can I extract IPA file from my iPhone to Mac?

Tags: ios, security, ipa, macos-catalina, internal-storage

I have one iOS application, which I have downloaded from appstore. Now I want to extract that application to check internal storage.

I have tried in macOS catalina, here I am not able to install itunes and not able to see phone apps in app explorer.
My macOS is catalina 10.15.3

So how can I extract the IPA from iPhone to mac?

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is *not* a code writing service; please post what you have tried so far (as a [mcve]) and any issues encountered. See [ask].

Comment: Did you solve it by chance?

Comment: This used to be possible via iTunes, but I don't know how to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless the iPhone is jailbroken.